# Laravel: Comparing dates between two columns in database not working

Tags: php, sql, laravel, date

We are trying to build and api with our project. My problem is when I need to get a specific event which has a column `date_from` and `date_to` it always gets the data even if the event was finished. I want to get the specific event that is been for the rest of the two dates. My thing is when the `date_from` and the `date_to` equal or grater than the date today, It will show and after the date is finished it will not. Here are some of my codes.

Index

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $person = User::find(Auth::user()->id); 
        $now = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
        if(empty($person))
            return response()->json([
                'code' => '03',
                'status' => 'Invalid User'
            ], 403);
        $role = $person->role;
        if ($role == 2 || $role == 3) {
            $level = Event::active()->with(['groups'])
            ->where('school_id', '=', $person->school_id)
            ->where('group_id', '=', $role)
            ->orWhere('group_id', '=', $person)
            ->where('status', '=', 1)
            ->where('active', '=', 1)
            ->whereRaw("date_from <=  date('$now')")
            ->whereRaw("date_to >=  date('$now')")

            ->get();


            return response()->json($level);
        }
```

Result in Postman

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Final",
        "content": "<p>Sample</p>",
        "group_id": 2,
        "event_date": "2019-09-01", 
        "date_from": "2019-09-20", //sept 20, 2019. The event started
        "date_to": "2019-10-03",//oct, 3 2019. The event end date. still gets the data even the date was not today.
        "time_from": "16:15:00",
        "time_to": "22:15:00",
        "event_place": "Room",
        "image": "",
        "school_id": 1,
        "smsnotify": 0,
        "appnotify": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "active": 1,
        "updated_by": null,
        "created_at": "2019-09-27 08:29:13",
        "updated_at": "2019-10-04 06:18:43",
        "users_id": 2,
        "groups": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Teachers",
            "description": "Teachers",
            "updated_by": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    }
```

Comment: `->whereRaw("date_to >=  date('" . $now . "')")`

Comment: You can use `where('date_from', '<=' ,date('$now'))`

Comment: still getting the same data in postman sir. @ZainFarooq

Comment: not working sir. still keep getting the data @jitheshjose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$now`, as you have defined it, should already be the date only component of the current timestamp.  So there should be no reason not to use regular `where()`:

```
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateString();

$level = Event::active()->with(['groups'])
    ->where('school_id', '=', $person->school_id)
    ->whereIn('group_id', [$role, $person])
    ->where('status', '=', 1)
    ->where('active', '=', 1)
    ->where('date_from', '<', $now)
    ->where('date_to', '>=', $now->addDays(1))
```

I am assuming in my answer that you want to avoid today.  The logic for this is that the date is earlier than today's date at midnight, or on or after midnight of tomorrow.

Besides the date issue, your handling of the `group_id` using `where()` and `orWhere()` might have been causing problems.  Your intention in SQL is the following:

```
WHERE (group_id = $role OR group_id = $person)
```

Note carefully the parentheses.  But, as you wrote it, because of order of operations it might come out not as you intended.

Comment: Still getting the data sir from postman. But when I do other comparison like `status=0` it will work. Only the dates is not working

Comment: I discovered something sir. If i comment out the `->orWhere('group_id', '=', $person)` it will work. but what should i to in order to not delete the `orWhere` ?

Comment: @RonaldBustillo I picked up on this as well.  You should use `whereIn` here.

Comment: Oh so the `orWhere` clause is the problem sir? Whats wrong with using `orWhere` than `whereIn`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$level = Event::active()->with(['groups'])
            ->where([['school_id', '=', $person->school_id],['group_id', '=', $role],['status', '=', 1],['active', '=', 1]])
            ->orWhere('group_id', '=', $person)
            ->whereRaw("CURDATE() between date_from and date_to")
            ->get();
```

Comment: Still getting the data sir from postman. But when I do other comparison like status=0 it will work. Only the dates is not working

Comment: I discovered something sir. If i comment out the `->orWhere('group_id', '=', $person)` it will work. but what should i to in order to not delete the `orWhere`?

Comment: Edited answer please try like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$level = Event::active()->with(['groups'])
  ->where('school_id', '=', $person->school_id)
  ->whereIn('group_id', [$person,$role])
  ->where('status', '=', 1)
  ->where('active', '=', 1)
  ->where('date_from', '<=', $now)
  ->where('date_to', '>=', $now->addDays(1))
  ->get();
```

Comment: still the same sir

Comment: Note that the above `WHERE` logic would only match records where the from and to date happen to both land on midnight of today.

Comment: So i have to add `$now->addDays(1)` inorder to work properly.right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your carbon date should match the format which is set in your database server

```
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateString()->format('Database Format');
```

Plus you don't need to pass your date variable inside date function

```
 ->where('date_from', '<', $now)
```

Comment: Thanks about that sir. The problem is on my code in the `orWhere` clause thats why it keeps getting the data even if the date comparison is correct. See @Tim Biegeleisen answer